# What Condition is Necessary to assume a Function is Independent of a Variable

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have a system of equations for the concentration, $c=c(x,z,t)$. After some simplifying assumptions though, I am left with the following boundary conditions and PDE:
$$ c_z=c_{zzz}=0, \qquad \text{on  } z=0,h(x,t) $$
$$ c_{zzzz}=0 $$
Can I say that $c$ is independent of $z$? I feel like I should be able to, however, I can't cite any specific reasoning and I'm not quite sure over which intervals to integrate the fourth-order equation.. i.e. over the interval $(0,z), (0,h)$ or $(z,h)$?

Comment: This is what I did and I was able to satisfy the conditions without much trouble. My concern though is how do I know $c(x,z,t)$ isn't made up of trigonometric functions, or logarithmic functions, or something else that end up cancelling at the boundaries? I suppose we can rule out trig functions since $c_{zzzz}=0$ everywhere not just at the boundary. However, I feel like their perhaps exist some function I haven't thought of other than a simple polynomial.